# How to manage Google Contacts via Google Apps Script? (errors with permission)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I have tried all sorts of things I have read and can think of:

Added the scope to the manifest file:

```
    {
      "timeZone": "America/Fortaleza",
      "dependencies": {
        "enabledAdvancedServices": [
          {
            "userSymbol": "People",
            "version": "v1",
            "serviceId": "peopleapi"
          }
        ]
      },
      "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
      ],
      "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
      "runtimeVersion": "V8"
    }
```

Enabled the People API in Services

I've deleted all apps permissions and started from scratch

I've tried changing the browser, in case cookies were a possibility

This is how I'm at this point trying to get a contact:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
        var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts"); 
        var rng = e.range;
        var row = rng.getRow();
        var drng = sht.getRange(row, 2, 1, 22).getValues();
        var email = sht.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    
        var gmailContact = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(email);
        Logger.log(gmailContact);
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:
You do not have the permission to call ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress Required permissions: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds

I'm trying to read contacts now and will get it updated as I edit a row containing an existing contact.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you are trying to run your script of `onEdit` as the simple trigger, please change the trigger to the installable trigger. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. At that time, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to other names to prevent duplicated running for both the simple and the installable triggers. If you have already been trying to run the script as the installable trigger, I apologize.

Comment: Right on, @Tanaike! ...as usual! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tanaike, the issues is due to the fact that this currently running on a simple trigger basis and not on an installable one. Thank you!

#### Reference:

[Simple Triggers > Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

Answer (score 1):

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

> Installable version can call services that require authorization. The installable version runs with the authorization of the user who created the trigger, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).